# How to determine what other css property/rule is sizing your html element

Tags: css

Sometimes you size an element and that's the size it is. But often in complex environments, there are a lot of factors that influence an element's dimensions.

Obviously the best way to determine what it determining the dimensions is by deep cognitive understanding of all the related elements and rules.

But I was wondering if there are any tools, like firebug or Chrome Developer Tools, that can help identify what other components are influencing the dimensions of the selected component.

Thanks

Chris

Comment: you have already mentioned the tools. Then what else you need.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, by sizing you mean the size that is generated after all the height, width, border and padding properties are applied.

In chrome, you can see the Computed Styles (right click element => inspect element) and determine which property is applied from which CSS selector.

[image]